# Systemd like PrivateTmp from a bash script

Tags: permissions, mount

When SSH-ing into a remote machine, I have a script that checks for an existing TMUX session. If an existing session is not found, then it will create a new session and attach to it.

I want to modify the script to automatically download and use my `tmux.conf` from GitHub, but prefer not to pollute the system with my configuration files. I was thinking of downloading the file to /tmp and using it. But I am a bit wary of keeping the files in a location, that is visible and accessible to everyone.

Is it possible to create a Systemd like `PrivateTmp` from a bash script?

On searching for this, I found the `unshare` program. But I cannot run it as an unprivileged user.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points

Comment: `/run/user/$uid`? What was the actual goal to use `/tmp`? I mean like is it tmpfs that you were after or what?

Comment: "but prefer not to pollute the system with my configuration files" – `.tmux.conf` in *your* home directory on the remote system is *yours* anyway, it does not pollute the system. Or is the home directory shared between users? Or do other people log in as the same user?

Comment: I wish to set an alias for `ssh` to run this script (the script itself will be downloaded from GitHub, and will run on the remote server). Eventually, I wish to update the script to setup my entire dot files, and set XDG_CONFIG_HOME and XDG_DATA_HOME to this directory. Effectively, I want to setup temporary private home directory.

Since I will be using this everywhere, the user I am connecting as doesn't necessarily have to be my account, it could be a shared user account.

Comment: `/run` might be mounted in RAM, and may not be sufficient. Because I will be running neovim with LSP, and if I open a workspace it will index the workspace and save it in XDG_DATA_HOME.